# Extruding plane creating extra loop cuts

Tags: modeling, extrude, fspy

This is my first ever Blender Stack exchange post. I am trying to use fSpy to recreate an interior. However, whenever I extrude the plane which I'm to align with the floor, it seems that extra loop cuts are made for every extrusion. I've tried extruding in vertex, edge, and face mode but this problem is still persisting. I've also tried selecting the extra loop cuts individual and deleting the edges. However, when I do this it ends up deleting some of the plane. I am trying to extrude the plane in such a way that no extra loop cuts will be made. Any tips would be much appreciated.

[image: e]

Comment: The extra "loop cuts" are normal when you extrude an edge. An extrusion extends the edge without removing the original edge, hence it's no "loop cut" because a cut adds edges where no edges were before. If you don't want those extra edges, you should simply move them with _G_ instead of extruding. Or if you want to get rid of them, instead of deleting an edge you should dissolve the edge. So hit _X_ > _Delete_ > _Dissolve Edges_ instead of _X_ > _Delete_ > _Edges_.

Comment: You can just use CTRL-X to dissolve edges or vertices rather than having to go through a menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to extend your plane without adding any extra edge loops it can be done by either moving it on the desired axis by pressing **'G'** and then pressing the desired axis **(eg. 'GX')** or scaling the mesh by pressing **'S'** and then pressing the desired axis. **(eg. 'SX')**.

**Scaling**

[image]

**Moving/grabbing**

[image]

Comment: "At the same time" sounds like you have to press both keys at once, but you can simply hit the key for the axis **after** hitting G for moving or S for scaling. And for the sake of completeness, if you want to move or scale in all directions except for e.g. the Z axis, you can press Shift + Z to constrain the action to X and Y.

Comment: oops sorry for that :(  the answer is updated.Thanks, Gordon :)